# Material Override on Custom Selection

Tags: cryptomatte

I have this example here where I have milk inside frosted glass.
I need a matte for the milk including the refractions on the glass.
Cryptomatte only gives me a matte for both objects combined.
In Maya I can simply make an override for the milk material and
get a matte just for the milk as a separate render layer.
Is something like this possible in Blender without creating a
separate scene?

thx

[image]